# Validate NSPredicate format

Tags: swift, nspredicate, nspredicateeditor, nspredicateeditorrow

In my app user can create `NSPredicate`s by using `NSPredicateEditor`.
I want to validate that user entered correct RegEx in `NSPredicateEditorRow` by testing NSPredicate.

```
@IBAction func predicateChanged(_ sender: NSPredicateEditor) {
//I want to test sender.predicate
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible in Objective-c and probably is possible in Swift.

Comment: @Willeke and how exactly is it possible?

Comment: In Objective-C I do `[predicate evaluateWithObject:someObject];` inside a @try and @catch block. `someObject` is a `NSDictionary` or other object which responds to the keys in the predicate editor.

Comment: ```@try``` and ```@catch``` doesn't catch anything, because ```evaluateWithObject``` doesn't throw na exception.

Comment: It does in my test app.

Comment: @Willeke your test app is in Swift?

Comment: No, it's Objective-C